# How to use the Rails with PostgreSQL to set the custom serial numbers by custom rules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'd like to set the rule to automatic generate the serial number.
I use the PostgreSQL.
There are two Tables; Store and Storerecord.
Store = [id, code], Storerecord = [id, Store_code, no]

Today, I have the store and the code is 'A01'.
I'd like to set the rule like A01+date+N or A01+random number.

If I need this kind format, how should I do to archive this goal?
Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `after_commit` callback to you model (unless you have some specific reason to have that serial number generation code to reside in your database itself).

So you do something like this in your **app/models/store.rb**:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Using after_commit, because we want to use ID of the record,
  # and it will be there only after record is saved to DB already
  after_commit :set_serial_number

  # other stuff you have in your model

  private

  def set_serial_number
    self.update_column(serial_number, self.id.to_s + self.code.to_s)
  end
end
```

Similar thing for your second model:

```
class Storerecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store

  after_commit :set_serial_number

  # other stuff you have in your model

  private

  def set_serial_number
    self.update_column(serial_number, self.store.id.to_s + self.no.to_s)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer!!!! :)) But, if I want to store the number in the Storerecord = [no], how could I catch the store_code and set the number?  Does it similar like above your answer?

Comment: @IanCheng You are welcome! :) Updated my answer above for your Storerecord.

Comment: How can I validate the `serial_number` so I know it's there and it's unique?
right now i have  
`validates :serial_number, presence: true, uniqueness: true`  
  `after_commit :create_serial_number, on: :create`  

  `def create_serial_number`  
    `self.serial_number = "s" + self.id.to_s + "uuid" + SecureRandom.uuid`  
  `end`  

but this doesn't work of course because validations happens after the commit. But id won't get assigned before commit, is there any way to work around this?

Comment: @DillonWreek One option is to go the other way around: just use UUID column as primary key. There are plenty of guides, e.g. https://pawelurbanek.com/uuid-order-rails